# Pool connection too many open files

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to scan my websites for urls that may contain a certain keyword. Now, I have a simple keyword file which contains things I want to scan for.

#### keywords.txt

```
help
faq
homepage
```

My script loops through the keywords and pools as a function to visit and check if them urls exist

```
# loop through keywords check website
for keyword in read_file(keywords):
    print("Scanning:", keyword)
    # Pool the connections to speed up scanning
    fun = partial(findfiles, output_file, keyword)
    with Pool(processes=max_processes) as pool:
        pool.map(fun, domains)
```

Which then runs my main code

```
def findfiles(output_file, keyword, domains):
# Strip the domain and add the keyword
domain = domains.strip()
url = ''.join(['http://', domain, '/', keyword])

try:
    with urlopen(url, timeout=5) as response:
        # Ignore redirects
        if response.geturl() != url:
            return
except URLError:
    return
except HTTPError:
    return
except timeout:
    return
except:
    return
else:
    # Write match to output_file
    with open(output_file, 'a') as file_handle:
        file_handle.write(url)

    # Write match to the console
    print("[*] Found:", url)
```

But I get an error saying the following

```
File "./checker.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "./checker.py", line 71, in main
    with Pool(processes=max_processes) as pool:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 176, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 241, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 20, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 69, in _launch
    parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

but my ulimit is 'unlimited', so what is causing this issue and how can I fix it?